# Mailing Multiple Users Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am trying to send an email to multiple users. I have a model that sends @users, which has all of the users I am going to be mailing... now when in the User_mailer I am having trouble figuring out how to tell the mail_out process to send to each of the users (set each recipient the user.email). To summarize, I want to set a cron job to run the User.mail_out process each morning, have it email each user in the @users variable being passed to the User_mailer model. Can someone please suggest a way of doing this? I am currently getting the following error when using what I have written below:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/runner.rb:48: /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/smtp.rb:680:in `check_response': 501 5.1.3 Bad recipient address syntax (Net::SMTPSyntaxError)
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_authentic
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create
validates_presence_of :birthday => "cannot be left blank"

  def self.mail_out

    weekday = Date.today.strftime('%A').downcase

    @users = find(:all, :conditions => {"#{weekday}sub".to_sym => 't'})




    UserMailer.deliver_mail_out(@users)



  end


end
```

User_Mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    def mail_out(users)
    @recipients = { }
    users.each do |user|
      @recipients[user.email]
    end


    from        "somewhere.net"
    subject     "Check it out"
    body        :user => @recipients
  end


  def subscribe(user)
    recipients  user.email
    from        "somewhere.net"
    subject     "Welcome!"
    body        :user => user
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'body' parameter in your #mail_out method is meant to be a hash of values that will be interpolated into the email template, not a hash of recipients. it should look like this:

```
def mail_out(users)
 recipients  users.collect(&:email)
 from        "somewhere.net"
 subject     "Check it out"
 body        {:var => 'value to interpolate into email'}
end
```

Theres a nice cheatsheet here:
http://dizzy.co.uk:80/ruby_on_rails/cheatsheets/action-mailer

Comment: Thank you, I am getting closer... although I get this error now:   SyntaxError (/home/tnederlof/Dropbox/Ruby/daily_trailer/app/models/user_mailer.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'

Answer (score 1):

```
recipients    ['mail1@example.info', 'mail2@example.com']
```